# Is there a way to prevent some one to execute a php that he must download it

Tags: php, file, upload, execute

My question is, if I have a file upload website, and some one host a PHP file, and I always force the server to download it, exists some way for the hack execute the php on my server instead of download it?

My code:

```
<?php 
$file = "files/" . $_GET["file"];
if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Make sure you don't save the file into the document root. The webserver shouldn't execute scripts outside this.

Comment: Be sure to upload user files into a folder that can't be accessed directly.

Comment: However, you should validate the name in `$_GET["file"]`. If the value begins with a sequence of `..`, they can download files outside the `files` directory.

Comment: Yes, if `files/` is web accessible then `http://www.example.com/files/file.php` would execute on the server.

Comment: If they send something like `$GET["file"] = "../../etc/passwd"` they could download this critical file.

Comment: You can use `.htaccess` to prevent running scripts in `/files/XXX`.

Comment: Thank you guys, help me a lot.